# Flyway 3.1 DB migration Multiple schemas - Oracle 11g

Tags: database, oracle, schema, flyway

Currently we are able to deploy DB scripts (ddl, dml,views/packages) in one schema at a time on oracle 11g.

(1) Is it possible to deploy DB scripts in multiple schemas (each schema has its own DB user and DB password) at the same time in one feature release deployment.

(it is most commonly used requirement)

It appears in flyway 3.1, the flyway.properties support 1 log DB user and DB password at a time,

Feature: New drop down
Schema:  schema A, Schema B, Schema C
(each schema has its own Db user, password however the JDBC url is same for all the 3 schemas. They all reside in oracle 11g database)

Can anyone encountered such an issue before, is there any flyway recommended solution or suggestions,

Folder: /sql 
Scripts:
: v1__Deploy_schema1.sql
    v1__Deploy_schema2.sql
    v1__Deploy_schema3.sql

Answer (score 0):

What I have done is to create a separate flyway/sql directory for each schema and then create a script for executing flyway migrate command for each schema simultaneously.

Comment: Have you also created a separate flyway.properties file for each schema since the flyway.user and flyway.password can be different for each schema?

Comment: Actually, I have a complete flyway installation for each schema, including the conf folder where the flyway.properties is located.

Comment: You can use <executions></executions> to handle this for you and put your configurations under each execution. Then you have different users and even can have different migration files for each.